# Background color for nav bar

Tags: html, css

I am very new to HTML/CSS and am having trouble structuring and coloring my nav bar. I have two problems.

1. I have my menu items in a ul list and they are displayed inline, but I need them to automatically structure themselves in a block if the screen width is changed.
2. I need to change the background color of "Adoptly" to red. I've only been able to color the word or manually style it, which doesn't work when the margins change.

This is what my code currently looks like:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <ul> 
      <li>Adoptly</li> 
      <li>About</li> 
      <li>Animals</li> 
      <li>Blog</li> 
      <li>Events</li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="supporting">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.header { 
  background-color: rgb(48, 98, 126);
  height: 75px;
}

.header li { 
  display: inline; 
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white; 
  font-size: 25px; 
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.header ul { 
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.header li:first-child {
  background-color: red; 
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

This is what the nav bar is meant to look like (ignore everything other than the nav bar): https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/adoptly/index.html

Thanks for your help,

Josh

Comment: Please post a complete code example in your question.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can do this by adjusting your current Media Query to:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .header li {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

2) You can do this by setting the LIs to `inline-block` and changing the height and `line-height` to `75px` to match the header height. You will also need to remove the top margin from the UL as well as setting the UL `height` to `75px`.

```
.header li { 
  display: inline-block; 
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white; 
  font-size: 25px; 
  margin-left: 20px;
  height:75px;
  line-height:75px;
}

.header ul { 
  height:75px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

## [Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/o8eBANVW6F)

Answer (score 0):

Here 's an little example, better to work with % than PX, for responsive design, and use HTML5 labels.

```css
       html,
       body {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
       }
       .container {
         display: block;
         position: relative;
         left: 20%;
         /* center responsive */
         max-width: 60%;
         width: 100%;
         /* Better work with % for responsive design */
         height: auto;
         margin: 0;
       }
       header {
         display: block;
         position: relative;
         background-color: rgba(48, 98, 126, .9);
         /* .9 opacity of color ;) */
         height: 75px;
       }
       ul {
         display: block;
         position: relative;
         height: 75px;
         line-height: 75px;
         list-style: none;
         max-height: 75px;
       }
       ul li {
         color: white;
         float: left;
         padding: 0 2rem;
       }
       .item-red {
         background-color: red;
       }
       /*
          MEDIASCREEN
          */
       @media screen and (max-width: 1700px) {
         .container {
           left: 15%;
           /* center responsive */
           max-width: 70%;
         }
       }
       /* End media screen */
       @media screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
         .container {
           left: 10%;
           /* center responsive */
           max-width: 80%;
         }
       }
       /* End media screen */
       @media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
         .container {
           left: 7.5%;
           /* center responsive */
           max-width: 85%;
         }
       }
       /* End media screen */
       @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
         .container {
           left: 0;
           /* center responsive */
           max-width: 100%;
         }
         ul {
           height: auto;
           line-height: auto;
           list-style: none;
           max-height: 100%;
         }
         ul li {
           background: #CCCCCC;
           display: block;
           float: none;
         }
       }
       /* End media screen */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li class="item-red">Adoptly</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Animals</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Events</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="supporting">
      <div class="container">
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a class for the word adoptly as shown above. Lets call it .main. In .main class youll deal with background-color,and color, then use padding from all sides to get the right ratio

Once you deal with the margins everything will evenly look nice.

This here will do the trick.

```
    .main {
  color:white;
  background-color: #e52364;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 22px 32px 22px 32px;
}
```